# How to restore a folder structure 7Zip'd with split volume option?

Tags: 7zip

I 7Zip'd a multi-gig folder which contained many folders each with many files using the split to volumes (9Meg) option. 7Zip created files of type .zip.001,
.zip.002, etc. When I extract .001 it appears to work correctly but I get an 'unexpected end of data' error. 7Zip does not automatically go to .002. When I extract .002, it also gives the same error and it does not continue the original folder/file structure. Instead it extracts a zip file in the same folder as the previously extracted files. How do I properly extract split files to obtain the original folder/file structure? Thank you.